# ASP.NET Cloudinary getting response

Tags: asp.net, cloudinary

I have little problem with using Cloudinary, I can upload the images it works fine but I guess i cant get any response from Cloudinary. Suggestion? about required parameters

Handler

```
 public async Task<Photo> Handle(Command request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                var photoUploadResult = _photoAccessor.AddPhoto(request.File);

                var photo = new Photo
                {
                    Url = photoUploadResult.Url,
                    Id = photoUploadResult.PublicId
                };     
                var success = await _context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;

                if (success) return photo;

                throw new Exception("Problem saving changes");
            }
```

Accessor

```
public PhotoUploadResult AddPhoto(IFormFile file)
    {
        var uploadResult = new ImageUploadResult();

        if (file.Length > 0)
        {
            using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
            {
                var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams
                {
                    File = new FileDescription(file.FileName, stream)
                };
                uploadResult = _cloudinary.Upload(uploadParams);
            }
        }

        if (uploadResult.Error != null)
            throw new Exception(uploadResult.Error.Message);

        return new PhotoUploadResult
        {
            PublicId = uploadResult.PublicId,
            Url = uploadResult.SecureUri.AbsoluteUri
        };
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

What do you get in response? Can you try:

```
string cloud_name = "<Cloud Name>";
        string ApiKey = "<Api-Key>";
        string ApiSecret = "<Api-Secret>";

        Account account = new Account(cloud_name,ApiKey,ApiSecret);
        Cloudinary cloudinary = new Cloudinary(account);
        cloudinary.Api.Timeout = int.MaxValue;

         var ImguploadParams = new ImageUploadParams()
            {
                File = new FileDescription(@"http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/couple.jpg"),
                PublicId = "sample",
                Invalidate = true,
                Overwrite = true
            };
        var ImguploadResult = cloudinary.Upload(ImguploadParams);
        Console.WriteLine(ImguploadResult.SecureUri);
```